# php include will not work one level up

Tags: php

I'm trying to include a file v-functions.php that's in htdocs/sc-dev/

The file I'm working on is in htdocs/sc-dev/accounts/verify

How do I write the include for the file v-functions so I can include it in index.php which is in /verify

I tried using include ('../../sc-dev/v-functions.php'); but that wont work, although it works fine in /accounts.

I'm running php 5.3.13 on Windows 7 Home Premium using apache server

Comment: If `htdocs` is your document root, best to use `"{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/sc-dev/v-functions.php"`

Comment: I think more to the point, although these answers are correct you need to figure out why your absolute paths aren't working the way you expect. @Fizzydrink has the correct answer for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could always use an absolute path, since you know it:

```
include("/htdocs/sc-dev/accounts/verify");
```

Alternatively, you can make use of the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` superglobal, which contains the base path of the website.

Comment: Why do you use parentheses for include ? Do you also write `echo('foobar')` ?

Comment: @tereško `include` is easier to consider a function, especially since it can return values. So, it just makes things easier to make it look like a function. `echo` can't return anything under any circumstance, so there's no reason to pretend it's a function.

Answer (score 3):

In mac os, it worked with:

```
    include('../../v-functions.php');
```

Comment: yup this is correct.  The reason his wasn;t working is because he was in the sc-dev directory already when trying to navigate to sc-dev

Answer (score 2):

You can just use [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) and step by step check which location you're getting with each "../".

Anyway path to the file you want:

```
htdocs/sc-dev/v-functions.php
```

Your current path:

```
htdocs/sc-dev/accounts/verify/somefile.php
```

Leaving once ("../"):

```
htdocs/sc-dev/accounts/
```

Leaving twice ("../../"):

```
htdocs/sc-dev/
```

Picking the file ("../../v-functions.php"):

```
htdocs/sc-dev/v-functions.php
```

I hope it will help you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute path. Use `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];` to find out what your root path is then set the directory path.